# Is this boolean answer correct?

Tags: boolean-algebra

F(x,y,z) = (x + y')(x + y)(xz')
         = (xx) + (xy) + (xy')+(y'y)(xz')
         = [x + (xy) + (xy') + 0 ] (xz') 
         = [x + x(y + y') + 0] (xz') 
         = [x + x(1) + 0] (xz')
         = [x + x + 0] (xz')
         = [x + x] (xz')
         = x*(xz') 
         = (xx)*z' 
         = xz'

xz' is my final answer.

Comment: $(xz')$ should be a factor in all the terms after you distribute.

Comment: Oh, you're right

Comment: @paw88789 ok, how about now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes, $$(x+y^\prime)(x+y)=x$$ and $$x(xz^\prime) = xz^\prime,$$ so your result is correct.